# How to use external speakers with hdmi cable

Tags: audio, hdmi, ps3

I have conected my ps3 to a pc monitor that has a hdmi cable input. However,  the monitor doesn't have built in speakers,  so I can't get any audio. I want to know if there's another way to get audio out from the ps3.

Comment: Does your monitor have a audio jack? Mine does, and I just attached the speakers to the monitor instead of computer. If not, the only way I could think of doing this would be to get a splitter or buy some more hardware.

Comment: I had the PS3 hooked up via an HDMI and then used the provided Component cable for audio, all that was needed was a stereo to headphone adapter.  The only complaint I had was that I had to control the volume on the speakers.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.  I use the old scart output (the cable came with the console) with white, red and yellow plugs to setup my audio.  The plugs goes as follows: yellow is for video (old analog video format) and white and red are for audio.  So all you have to do is plug the audio lines into your sound system as if a normal rc cable and then change from PS3 settings the audio output device.

This approach however requires something that covers audio input via RCA.  In my case I have 2.1 speaker setup (2 speakers + sub) which has input for audio.  With say, a headset this would not work as PS3 doesn't have support for 3.5mm audio jack.

Comment: *"a normal rc cable"* -- What is *"rc"*?  Do you mean "RCA", which is the name for the phono-type plugs?

Comment: @sawdust Indeed I got the term wrong there. RCA is the proper term.